# Adding resources to a Java project

Tags: java

I'm trying to add an icon to my JButton, but I keep getting an NullPointerException meaning that the image i specified cannot be found.

Both my classes and the buttonremoterefresh.png are directly inside the src folder (the classes are inside the default package). I have been googling this around since last night and no matter what I try, I can't manage to load the resource.

```
public class InfiltratorClient {

    private MainWindow mw;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        new InfiltratorClient();
    }

    public InfiltratorClient () {   
    mw = new MainWindow();      
    }
}


public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private InfiltratorClient n;


    public MainWindow() {

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
      this.setSize(650, 600);
      setVisible(true);
      contentPane = new JPanel();
      contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setContentPane(contentPane);
      contentPane.setLayout(null);

      JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
      btnNewButton.setBounds(258, 228, 140, 105);
      contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

      //In this Line i get the exception 
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MainWindow.class.getResource("buttonremorerefresh.png"));
      btnNewButton.setIcon(icon);

      repaint();
      revalidate();
 }
}
```

Comment: google "getResourceAsStream"...

Comment: Invoke MainWindow.class.getResource("").getPath() and be sure of the path where the image is being searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
 JButton button = new JButton();
      try {
        Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("buttonremorerefresh.png"));
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
      } catch (IOException ex) {
      }
```

Comment: It has worked, thanks a lot. I'm still not sure though what was the problem with the old code. Does java need to open a stream on every resource?

Comment: Here i use an image insted of imageicon